# docker failed to compute cache key: /path not found: not found

Tags: node.js, docker

I just started with the docker and I am creating docker image from my code. Here is the dir structure

```
project
  /deployment
     /Dockerfile.project1
  /services
     /ui
        /project1
```

and Here is the code in `Dockerfile.project1`

```
FROM node:14

# arguments
ARG BUILD_COMMIT
ARG BUILD_BRANCH
ARG BUILD_TAG
# port number for app
ARG PORT=3000
ARG APP=adam_website_ui

LABEL build.tag=${BUILD_TAG}
LABEL app=${APP}

# set the env
ENV BUILD_BRANCH=${BUILD_BRANCH}
ENV BUILD_COMMIT=${BUILD_COMMIT}


WORKDIR /app

# Assiging user
USER root
RUN echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'): ======> Setup Appusr" \
    && groupadd -g 1001 appusr \
    && useradd -r -u 1001 -g appusr appusr \
    && mkdir /home/appusr/ \
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /home/appusr/\
    && chown -R appusr:appusr /app

# copy the relavant code
COPY ../services/ui/project1 /app/

# installing deps
RUN npm install 
RUN npm run build
RUN SET PORT=${PORT} && npm start

USER appusr:appusr
```

but this is showing

```
 => ERROR [4/7] COPY ../services/ui/project1 /app/                                                                         0.0s 
------
 > [4/7] COPY ../services/ui/project1 /app/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/services/ui/project1" not found: not found
```

and I am building using this command from `deployment` folder

```
docker build -t website_ui -f Dockerfile.project1 .
```

what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run docker build within the directory `project/deployment` with build context `.`, then docker is not able to find the files in `project/services`.

Try to run `docker build -t website_ui -f deployment/Dockerfile.project1 .` (the last argument is the build context)

From the docs:

> The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a "context". A build's context is the set of files located in the specified `PATH` or `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a Docker image you must specify a path to a directory which will be the **build context**, this is the dot at the end of your `docker build` command.
The content of this directory will then be copied by Docker (probably into an internal Docker directory), which is why you can't `COPY` paths *outside* the context.

> You should see a message like *"Uploading context of X bytes"* when running `docker build`.

Change your `COPY` instruction to `COPY services/ui/project1 /app/` and build your image from the project's root directory:

```sh
docker build -t website_ui -f deployment/Dockerfile.project1 .
```

Read more about the build context on the [`docker build` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)